# Why was Darth Vader given a downgraded version of General Grievous's mechanics?

Tags: star-wars, nanotechnology

Darth Vader was given obsolete technology for his suit, as can be seen in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7131/98). It seems odd that he wouldn't have been given similar technology. Why was this done?

Comment: And yes, I know the answer is probably that CGI technology improved considerably in the 28 years between movies, but I would like an in universe answer please.

Comment: Because Mr. Lucas didn't give a damn about the new Star Wars movies...

Comment: I recall reading somewhere in the SW universe that since Anakin had been a mechanic, Vader was constantly tinkering with his suit, upgrading it as he desired.

Comment: @kjmccarx Well, can you blame him? Who did?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As you refer to the previous question, I'll refer to the previous [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7131/why-is-darth-vader-body-suit-considered-an-upgrade-to-general-grievous/7135#7135). Darth Sidious no longer needed an incredibly strong and dangerous Jedi warrior to protect him from a large number of hostile Jedi, to usurp the Republic. He needed a henchman capable of being a major threat to "normal" people while posing a reduced threat to Sidious, slowing the normal Sith progression of Apprentice defeating Master.

Additionally, the style of the armor is based on [Sith designs](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vader%27s_armor).

Comment: Too bad for him he didn't build the suit without arms.

Comment: As I said, "reduced" threat.

Comment: Also, it had to *look* intimidating. More importantly, it had to provide environment control; Grievous could breathe normal air on his own (if troubled later on).

Answer (score 23):

Could it be that General Grievous's suit would have diminished any abilities to use the Force? Vader's suit was made via Sith alchemy making it compatible with the midi-chlorians. Grievous's suit is almost entirely robotic apart from the brain, which was what gave the robot its advantage of sentient forethought and equilibrium.

Vader's suit:

> "The suit was constructed using various methods of Sith alchemy which
>   served to augment Vader's severely diminished physical strength and
>   vitality."

[From: Darth Vader's Armor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vader%27s_armor)

Comment: this.  Grievous wasn't in a 'suit' as much as he/it was basically just two lungs, a heart, and a brain inside of a droid.

Comment: I've always been curious to what Grevious' organs actually do the brain makes sense it thinks, but the lungs and heart, he's mostly a robot does he even have traditional blood or even the need for air to live, maybe to talk I guess but even still.

Comment: @Iankill: The brain needs oxygenated blood, thus the lungs and heart.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the suit being downgraded was that Palpatine wanted to confine Vader in order to prevent Vader from becoming more powerful and overthrowing Palpatine. One zap of force lightning and Vader's suit is fried.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific when you say **his suit** in the last sentence? Whose suit?

Comment: One zap of force lightning and people are fried too.  Like Palpatine's FACE.

Comment: @Oldcat But Palpatine survived the zap. Vader and his suit did not.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it was to keep Darth Vader as a force user. Anakin was insanely powerful in the force, whereas Darth Vader was still powerful, but his was a "*Shadow of the Power that he once held*." General Grievous' body was completely robotic, save for his heart and a few veins and nerves. Darth Vader's, in comparison, held as much of his organic tissue as possible. If he had Grievous' body, his connection to the force would have been all but non existent.

Comment: The previous consensus was that [losing limbs did not diminish Vader's strength in the Force](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4097/5184), it stands to reason that if losing limbs didn't do it, losing some more of his natural body likely wouldn't either.

Comment: Consensus by whom? In one of the books during the rise of Darth Ceadus, Lumiya admits that her and Vader could never be true masters of the force due to their prosthetics.

Comment: Consensus by the community here. Click through and read some of the answers on the question I linked. If you believe that the other answers are wrong, feel free to add your own.

Comment: @DarthEspo - before the whole midichlorian nonsense was started in the prequels, it was explained that a person's body was the focus for their connection to the Force. As the body was reduced, so was that connection. However, with the prequels that changed.