# Does Force training increase midi-chlorian density, or do Force abilities grow stronger in some other way?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, midichlorians

According to *Star Wars* lore, midi-chlorians are the microscopic entities which reside within living creatures and essentially act as a vector for the Force. They can be detected in blood, and have been linked to how powerful any Force user can be; the more midi-chlorians, the greater the power. This video expands upon it:

It has been inferred that high midi-chlorian count doesn't *necessarily* equate to over all greater Force power... just as genes don't essentially dictate a child's exact capabilities, so much so as their *potential* for it (Micheal Jordan's kids, even possessing his *genes,* won't necessarily have his same design which was suited for basketball, *or* his *talent* for example.)

However, its **also** been inferred that Force powers can be improved by practice and training, and not just like "skill building"... as in becoming so adept with knife throwing in focus, aim and neuro-muscular action that after a year one can fire off knives repeatedly, more quickly and with an aim that can more accurately hit targets... No. The implication is that Force powers can be improved by actually getting *stronger,* like a muscle being able to lift more and more **weight** after continuous resistance training.

Does this happen because the midi-chlorian *count* increases, or the user's skill *with* the exact same number increases?

Is there some way to "disrupt" midi-chlorian connection to the user to remove their Force powers?

And why are Force powers somehow stronger in certain areas than others? Is this because the midi-chlorians themselves are being "charged" some way, or increasing in number?

Comment: From ROTS, we've learned that Darth Plagueis can influence midi-chlorians to create life. From Episode I, Quin-Gon explained to Anakin that they exist in cells in order to communicate the will of The Force, these act like a vessel, their number explains one's affinity to The Force, so I do not think so.

Comment: There is very little mention of midichlorians outside of the prequel trilogy (perhaps because of fan reaction?). There's probably not a lot to go on.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with a point I'll already covered in [another anserw](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231151/does-darth-maul-lose-force-potential-when-obi-wan-cuts-his-lower-half-off/)

**Misconception**

Midi-chlorian **are not** The Force nor they create it. They are just "indicators" of the innate potentials. They do not determinate the upper cap you can reach, since training in the Force makes you stronger;

as noted [in Star Wars official site](https://www.starwars.com/news/so-what-the-heck-are-midi-chlorians):

> *So, despite blood-tests that show your aptitude, learning the Force is still like Yoga, or boxing. You might be born more lithe, or bigger and stronger, but, because we all have midi-chlorians in us, we can all develop the Force to lesser or greater extents — in the world of Star Wars.*

and [in the Star Wars wiki](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian):

> *A misconception exists that rather than being indicators, midi-chlorians actually are the Force or create it; there is no canonical basis for this belief.*

---

*Does this happen because the midi-chlorian count increases, or the user's skill with the exact same number increases?*

The midi-chlorian count do not change, you just became more skilled. They are mere indicators of youe innate potential. On the other hand, by training, the skill of the user can growth.

*Is there some way to "disrupt" midi-chlorian connection to the user to remove their Force powers?*

Force Powers do not depends on midi-chlorians. There anyway techniques to suppress the connection of a user with the Force. In Legends, there is the Force Power called [Force Suppression](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_suppression), while in the canon-game [Jedi Fallen Order](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Jedi:_Fallen_Order) you found a former Jedi who had voluntarily suppressed his connection with the Force. It's possible, but is not really Midi-chlorians related.

*And why are Force powers somehow stronger in certain areas than others? Is this because the midi-chlorians themselves are being "charged" some way, or increasing in number?*

Again, the Force Powers are not related to midi-chlorians. There are places that are "strong with the Force", for example the [Dagobah planet.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dagobah) In places like that it's easier to connect with the Force and so use Force Powers. As result, they appears somehow stronger, I'll try to explain it with an example:

> Imagine to  lift a a cube of metal of the weight of 50 kg. Than do the same on the moon, for istance. You'll lift it much easier on the moon and for an outside looker it will seems you are much stronger on the moon, meanwhile it was just **easier** for you to do it.