# Could Darth Vader Control the Empire

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith, darth-vader, darth-sidious

With Darth Vader's famous line "join me, and together we can defeat the Emperor". Even if he did end up defeating the Emperor, could he control the Empire? Does he have enough political power? or would the Imperial Senate elect a new head.

Comment: Is this déjà vu?

Comment: @Null : I feel like a question with *exactly* the same wording as the one above (about taking over the Empire) was asked about a week ago.

Comment: @Praxis Yeah, I'm thinking of one similar, too. I'm looking for it but I haven't found it.

Comment: Also related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20768/why-didnt-vader-let-luke-kill-the-emperor-or-even-kill-him-himself?rq=1

Comment: I don't see how that is a duplicate. "Does he sincerely want to" is rather different from "is he actually capable of", especially when you are talking about a severely damaged person/half android with a total lack of impulse control and no discernible political instinct whatsoever.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I agree. These are related questions but I don't think they're duplicates.

Comment: The difference between the two question while not vast, is also engaging in speculation we do not normally like to engage in on this site since the canon information regarding the question has already been answered. Everything else being questioned is merely opinion or speculation and as such is beyond the scope of this site. The question offers no substantial improvement to our overall knowledge of Star Wars.

Comment: I think the issue here is that he certainly thought so. And let's face it, who's going to stop him?

Comment: The Senate was dissolved in Episode IV, wasn't it...?