# Why did Vader need a big control panel on his suit's chest?

Tags: star-wars

After reading [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7137/why-was-darth-vader-given-a-downgraded-version-of-general-grievouss-mechanics) and [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7131/why-is-darth-vader-body-suit-considered-an-upgrade-to-general-grievous), I read [Darth Vader's armor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vader%27s_armor#Discomfort_and_limitations) article on Wookieepedia. This passage made me frown :

> The monitoring panel beeped frequently and for no reason, the lights seeming to serve only as steady reminders of his vulnerability. His electrical systems were woefully delicate, and he was forced to protect his vital chest panel when dueling. This system was so vulnerable that Antinnis Tremayne was once able to deactivate Vader's entire suit by pressing one button on his chest control plate.

The suit, and more specifically the helmet, use some high technology for the interface. But the chest control panel is made of huge lights and big freaking switches, just like if it was salvaged from an archaeological museum. It was even replaced on at least two occasions, but its odd design was globally kept.

[image: Vader's chest panels]

Why incorporate such patent weakness to the armor? And why would Vader tolerate it?

Comment: i think the answer probably lies here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7137/why-was-darth-vader-given-a-downgraded-version-of-general-grievouss-mechanics

Comment: Why have an off switch on your life support in the first place?

Comment: The buttons have to be big so that he can hit them easily while wearing gloves.

Comment: Or, maybe he was using [Aromatherapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aromatherapy). "My scars are itching, here, a shot of Lavender! Hum... (Sniff)... Ha!"

Comment: @TGat: For the same reason that nearly all life support equipment have off switches or are otherwise capable of being turned on/off at will (including pacemakers). Sometimes there are procedures (repair/maintenance/replacement/removal/diagnostics/etc.) that requires a piece of machinery to be turned off/suspended or restarted. That's why life support systems on submarines/planes/space vehicles/etc. also have off switches. That's also why power stations have off switches.

Comment: @TGat: The button size issue is something faced by astronauts as well. As I understand it, the torso-mounted cameras used during the Moon landings were very difficult for astronauts to operate, both, because of their gloves and because they couldn't see where the buttons were.

Comment: @TGnat: Those aren't really gloves, they are *his hands*. Clearly Vader is no good at manipulating delicate objects, unless he uses the Force to do it. Fly fishing will be a problem.

Comment: See also http://www.savagechickens.com/2016/06/vader-buttons.html "Vader Buttons", a Savage Chickens comic strip about Vader's control panel.

Comment: "Sir, word is Anakin Skywalker has turned to the Dark Side and started calling himself 'Lord Vader'" -- "This again?  That guy just hasn't been the same since that volcano duel with Obi-Wan.  Look, have you tried turning him off and back on again?"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's only one reason that you build an obvious vulnerability into a system - to keep it from getting out of control. I would guess that to get close enough to mess with those controls (without Vader being able to stop you), you'd have to be pretty powerful. After the events of Revenge of the Sith, there were not many beings left in the universe that powerful aside from the Emperor.

In short, I'd say it was a reminder to Vader that the Emperor could turn him off with the press of a toggle switch if he get out of control.

EDIT: So how did a Padawan (Antinnis Tremayne) achieve it? Vader allowed it, seeing who could think beyond a simple direct attack...the exercise was a test of lateral thinking.

Comment: If it was a test, is it possible that the panel is a dummy?  Perhaps it's there to draw attention and provide a clearly marked 'weak point' to draw attacks...though 'center of mass, above heart' is a bad choice for target placement...

Comment: Ooh...that's a good idea, too. I think one of the iterations of Batman had that, with an armored plate right beneath the insignia.

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily have to be _that_ close to mess with the controls: _force-flip-switch_, _Vader defeated._

Comment: @NaftuliKay: and Vader does force-flip-switch-back. How boringly unhelpful that action was attacking Vader.

Comment: It's mostly because he's such a drama queen...remember the scene where his lightsaber menacingly appears in the fog?  He apparently turned off his whole life support system just for that effect.