# What do the buttons on Darth Vader's suit do?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

In all three of the original trilogy not once does anyone interact with (or even discuss) those damn buttons on his chest plate.

Do they do anything?  Is there a reference to them in the extended universe of what they do?

Comment: Did you check this site? the question seems familiar

Comment: I did.  Couldn't find an answer.  If you find a duplicate let me know and I will mark this question as [duplicate].

Comment: That being said, @Thomas, what the hell do those buttons do?  And why are they right at pressing height for most opponents?  Are they super unimportant?  Or very important?  Will music start playing if you press one?

Comment: I've found it. it isn't a direct answer but instead related:
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7144/why-did-vader-need-a-big-control-panel-on-his-suits-chest

Comment: Yep, that works.  Thanks!

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and back on again?"

Comment: @OrganicMarble - That's what [Padmé does in Attack of the Clones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9MsXi7n0NU&t=26s) and look where that got her.

Answer (score 2):

> [image]
> <sub><sup>[Vader - a 3-D Reconstruction Log](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Vader:_A_3-D_Reconstruction_Log)</sup></sub>

> The chest plate is Vader's life systems computer. The silver bands that
> bracket both sides of the box are life functions sensor arrays that
> constantly monitor Vader's heath, The “coin slots” lining the left
> hand side use color-coded lights to display the status of pulmonary
> systems, regulatory systems, and neural systems.
>
> The colored squares to the right of the shits are command switch
> override, the auto/manual switch, and the system reset switch,
> underneat those is a row of four programming touchplates.
>
> For those wondering why Vader would have such vulnerable controls
> displayed on his chest, take note that most buttons won't work with a
> simple touch. The control activator is housed on one of those “garage
> door opener" [on his belt] - only when this button is touched will the
> chest plate controls work
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Insider 81](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_81)</sup></sub>

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Blueprints: The Ultimate Collection](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Blueprints:_The_Ultimate_Collection)</sup></sub>

Comment: There's a reset switch attached to his chest? Seriously? Wonder what would happen if that got pressed during battle...

Comment: @user25730 - The answer is "nothing". The buttons don't work unless Vader activates them first

Comment: well that's no fun. I just want someone, during a fight, to press the reset button and Vader starts choking. Better yet, mess with the temperature controls and see him go up in flames.