# Was there any in-Universe mention of a technology to clone individual organs/limbs?

Tags: star-wars, clones

As part of answering " [Why are Anakin and Luke fitted with cybernetic hands?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7483/why-are-anakin-and-luke-fitted-with-cybernetic-hands/7494#7494) ", I tried to remember any mention of a canonical (any canon) technology to grow a cloned organ or a limb - as opposed to a full cloned being.

I couldn't come up with any example but thought that it's worth asking about in case I was wrong.

**Was there any SW in-Universe mention of a technology to clone individual organs/limbs?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've read most of the novels set post-ROTJ (through the end of the Vong war), seen the movies, but have not watched all of 'The Clone Wars' or the CW movie.  I haven't read any prequel (Clone War era or earlier) books.

I've never seen mention of this technology, even when it would have made sense for it to be used.

Honestly, medical tech in the SW Universe doesn't seem very advanced - if a dunk in bacta won't fix it, you live with it (or die).

Comment: Yes.  Take Ton Phanan from wraith squadron, for example.  He was allergic to bacta, kept getting injured and ended up a significant portion machine.

Comment: Exactly.  If they could clone new parts, surely the friggin doctor would know about it.

Comment: I suppose that if you have a wonder-substance like bacta, you're less likely to develop other advanced medicines and treatments...